# Whether or not to use new url parameter in jquery 1.5 ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I notice from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings that `jquery` v1.5 onwards allows us to use either

```
jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] )
```

or just

```
jQuery.ajax( [ settings ] )
```

and specify the url in `settings.url`. Is there any advantage (or disadvantage) to specifying the url as a separate parameter rather than as a property of the `settings` object?

Comment: Do you mean the *new* parameter, released *January 31, 2011*?

Comment: @freedomn-m haha yes that's the one. I'm really up to date you know! I'm just writing a wrapper class and wanted to know if there was a reason to go for one over the other. Thanks. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 0):

The ajax module was rewritten for 1.5: https://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/

At the top of the jquery `$.ajax` method is this check:

```
    // If url is an object, simulate pre-1.5 signature
    if ( typeof url === "object" ) {
        options = url;
        url = undefined;
    }
```

so there's no functional difference as it will handle either method (assuming the `url` in `(url,settings)` is a string).

Further down, it does:

```
s.url = url || s.url;
```

so the url outside the settings overwrites the one inside if both are provided.

This allows you to create a general, reusable ajax settings object to be used with different urls.

The key here is further down:

```
s = jQuery.ajaxSetup( {}, options )
```

this applies any previous calls to `$.ajaxSetup` to the options, meaning you can setup all your ajax settings in `$.ajaxSetup` and then they don't need to be passed to `$.ajax` which can be a simple url, eg:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: { html: "<b>ok</b>" }, 
    method: "POST"
});

// now call $.ajax with just the url
$.ajax("/echo/html")
    .done(function(h) { $("#o3").html(h) });
```

Without the separate string url parameter, this would need to be

```
$.ajax({ url: "..." })
```

This is demonstrated in this fiddle (which uses fiddle's `/echo/html` for ajax calls)

https://jsfiddle.net/2mnr8ok5/

---

> Is there any advantage (or disadvantage) to specifying the url as a separate parameter rather than as a property of the settings object?

If you're passing a settings object and it has a url, then there's no advantage to call

```
$.ajax(settings.url, settings);
```

if you're using `$.ajaxSetup` and just changing the url, then passing as a string will be more convenient that creating an object with just the url within.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent comprehensive answer. I would just add that the official docs advise against using ‘ajaxSetup’

Comment: Do you have a link for that?  I always use `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

Comment: At the top of https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/ it says "Its use is not recommended" and the Note section says "The settings specified here will affect all calls to $.ajax ... For that reason we strongly recommend against using this API. Instead, set the options explicitly in the call or define a simple plugin to do so."